# Trial period for an android app

Tags: android

My app uses IAB for the purchase of premium features, i was thinking about offerring a trial period for users to try out the features.

What is the best way to offer trial periods? A user should be able to try it only once, so a boolean is out of question as someone would keep resetting the app data.

I was thinking about using the play store game services, and use the cloud save feature where i would save my boolean.
How much space would i need for game services? My app is 700kb and i don't want to exceed 1mb
Are there any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you've stated - number one priority is that the data about the trial is kept on a remote server that users cannot access. You could keep a database of features and assign unique (primary) keys once a user installs your application on a new device and then search for the key in your database. If you find it, activate the trial feature and delete the entry from the database so that user won't be eligible for the trial promotion in the future. This would also allow you to manually add entries in case a user complains or a part of code malfunctions and prevent the user from experiencing the feature.

EDIT: Natively, Android supports [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) databases so I'd suggest you follow their guidelines when designing the database. As for managing the database and querying it, I used [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) tutorial to start learning it. However, I think it's best that the querying and verification is done on the server side, as you have no level of certainty over Android hardware capabilities

Comment: This is a neat idea for the part where something might go wrong so i can manually reset it, would you be able to provide me with a link to do something like this? 
I don't know anything about this stuff

Comment: Added a couple of links for beginning SQLite database development in the original answer